# does make_unique value initializes char array

Tags: c++, c++11, memory, c++14, smart-pointers

For example -

```
#include <memory>

int main(){
    const auto bufSize = 1024;
    auto buffer = std::make_unique<char[]>(bufSize);
}
```

Is the buffer here already filled with `'\0'` characters or will I have to manually fill it to avoid garbage values.

And what would be the possible way to do this, will `std::memset(&buffer.get(), 0, bufSize)` suffice?

Comment: Is there a reason you're using `std::unique_ptr<char[]>` instead of `std::vector<char>`?

Comment: You wouldn't need the `std::memset` to initialize all to `0` because `std::make_unique<char[]>(bufSize)` will use the expression `new char[bufSize]()`. Notice the default initialization, `()`

Comment: @TartanLlama yes.

Comment: IIRC, if the datum is a class member, a std::vector will allocate some space, and then allocate again on the inevitable resize.  (Others have looked at implementations and come to this conclusion.) The buffer pointer can just be null until allocated.  As written here it makes no difference, but it matters in other cases.

Comment: I'm here because I want to allocate and manage a buffer using `unique_ptr` but, at some point, hand it off to a C function as a raw pointer with `buffer.release()`.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58050872/what-does-stdmake-unique-for-overwrite-do-isnt-it-redundant-with-stdmake

Answer (score 42, accepted):

All of the `make_*` functions use value-initialization for the type if you don't provide constructor parameters. Since the array-form of `make_unique` doesn't take any parameters, it will zero-out the elements.

Comment: `make_heap` doesn't.

Comment: `make_unique_for_overwrite` doesn't either.

Answer (score 13):

Yes, all the elements will be [value initialized](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization) by [std::make_unique](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique).

> The function is equivalent to:
>
> ```
> unique_ptr<T>(new typename std::remove_extent<T>::type[size]())
> ```

and

> value initialization
>
> This is the initialization performed when a variable is constructed
>   with an empty initializer.
>
> Syntax
>
> ```
> new T (); (2)
> ```

and

> The effects of value initialization are:
>
> 3) if `T` is an array type, each element of the array is
>   value-initialized;
>   4) otherwise, the object is zero-initialized.

then for each element of type `char`, they'll be value-initialized (zero-initialized) to `'\0'`.

Answer (score 9):

According to [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique), yes:

> 2) Constructs an array of unknown bound T. This overload only participates in overload resolution if T is an array of unknown bound. The function is equivalent to:
>
> ```
> unique_ptr<T>(new typename std::remove_extent<T>::type[size]())
>                                        value initialization ^
> ```

Value initialization indicated by me.