# Correctly reinterpreting array of struct of int as array of int

Tags: c++, struct, cuda, pointer-aliasing

I have a `std::vector` of a custom struct which contains two integers (and only two integers):

```cpp
struct S {
    int p0;
    int p1;
};
```

```cpp
std::vector<S> v(dimension);
```

I want a pointer to this array of struct, to be interpreted as an array of int with twice the original dimension.
The context is the following one: the `std::vector` of struct (here, `v`) is constructed in some legacy code. In my own code, this array has to be communicated to a GPU (through `cudaMemcpy`).

The first solution would be to re-generate a new array of `int` with twice the dimension of the original array. Then communication of the new array of `int` to the GPU goes straightforwardly.

However, I want to avoid making this copy on the CPU memory, to save time and memory usage.
Instead, I hope to safely get a pointer to the first element of the vector of structs. Can I be sure that this is safe ? Can I be sure that the `p0`, `p1` fields are aligned on the memory as `(p0, p1, p0, p1, ...)` when reading through `v`? In other words, can I be sure that the `*(ptr+2*i)` and `*(ptr+2*i+1)` will be the `p0` and `p1` integers, respectively, of the `i`-th element of the original array `v`, when `ptr` points to the tip of this original array?

Below is a minimalistic self-contained illustrative example. From this piece of code, it seems that everything goes well. Will this be always the case?

```cpp
/*
Compilation: nvcc main.cu -o main.cuda
or g++ main.cpp -o main when removing cudaMemcpy's and cudaFree
*/
#include <vector>
#include <cassert>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>

struct S {
    int p0;
    int p1;
};

int main()
{
    assert(sizeof(S)==2*sizeof(int));

    unsigned int n = 10;
    unsigned int dimension = (1UL)<<n; // =2^n

    std::vector<S> v(dimension);
    // initialize array of struct - done in legacy code
    int shift = 10;
    for (int i=0; i<dimension; ++i) {
        v[i].p0 = shift+2*i;
        v[i].p1 = shift+2*i+1;
    }

    int *d_v;
    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_v, 2*dimension*sizeof(int));

    // solution 1 - to be avoided - re-allocate the array on CPU memory and copy values to GPU
    std::vector<int> v2(2*dimension);
    for (int i=0; i<dimension; ++i) {
        v2[2*i] = v[i].p0;
        v2[2*i+1] = v[i].p1;
    }
    cudaMemcpy(d_v, v2.data(), 2*dimension, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    // solution 2 (?)
    int * ptr = (int*)v.data(); // safe ?
    // ptr should point to the "p0" field of the first element of v. Let's check:
    for (int i=0; i<2*dimension; ++i) {
        assert( *(ptr+i) == shift+i ); // Ok. Is it always true ?
    }
    cudaMemcpy(d_v, ptr, 2*dimension, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice); // Is it fully safe ?

    /* ... use d_v in Cuda kernels */

    cudaFree(d_v);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `assert(sizeof(S)==2*sizeof(int));` Make this `static_assert(sizeof(S)==2*sizeof(int));` (with a second parameter containing a string literal to use as error message prior to C++20). This will make compilation fail instead of executing the check at runtime and only for debug configurations.

Comment: You can also use an integer type with a more specific width (i.e. `std::uint32_t` instead of just `int`)

Comment: 3rd way: you also could use `std::copy` and possibilities given by optimization. 4th way: make a vector with allocator that uses CUDA (I'm surprised that they don't have such library).

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie They do, it's called [Thrust](https://nvidia.github.io/thrust/).

Comment: @paleonix *snap* neat!

Comment: I don't quite see why you want to get rid of `S` in device code. While SoA is generally better for performance than AoS, this isn't real SoA (i.e. one vector for `p0` and one for `p1`). Doing a bigger load can even improve performance depending on the context. That is why CUDA has "vector types" (nothing to d with C++ vector) like `int2`.

Comment: Beware of padding in your struct.

Comment: You would likely need something like alignas for the structure declaration (or some compiler specific equivalent), or declare the structure as union

Comment: Thanks for your comments. @paleonix, in my code, the struct `S` is actually made of two 64-bits integers, not two 32-bits as in the illustrative example above, which might prevent using Cuda's vector types (?). Actually, I don't specifically want to get rid of `S` in device code, but rather want to make **absolutely** sure that I can communicate the content of `v` (and, of course, keep it's ordering structure) as safely as if it were a simple array with twice the dimension.

Comment: There is also [`long2` and `longlong2`](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#built-in-vector-types). I would also recommend reading [CUDA Pro Tip: Increase Performance with Vectorized Memory Access](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/cuda-pro-tip-increase-performance-with-vectorized-memory-access/): "You can also generate vectorized loads using structures as long as the structure is a power of two bytes in size."

Comment: @Samuel Shouldn't you use a `SoA` (`S`truct `o`f `A`rray)  approach instead actually? I mean, this would be more robust than anything you could come up with since reinterpreting data like that is always... Adventurous. This would boil down to use `struct s{ int* p0; int* p1; }`, or even better `struct s{  vector<int> p0, p1; /*host*/ struct device_view{int* p0; int* p1; /*device, pass this to kernels*/}; };`

Answer (score 2):

You asked:

> In other words, can I be sure that the `*(ptr+2*i)` and `*(ptr+2*i+1)` will be the `p0` and `p1` integers, respectively, of the i-th element of the original array `v`, when `ptr` points to the tip of this original array?

Strictly speaking, I am unable to find anything in the language which guarantees that.

If you are able to verify that `sizeof(S)` is equal to `2*sizeof(int)`, I don't see any reason why that would not be true.

i.e., inserting the following line in your code should be a sufficient guarantee that your code does not use memory inappropriately.

```
static_assert(sizeof(S) == 2*sizeof(int), "Objects are not aligned properly");
```

---

On a separate note, I would change

```
int* ptr = (int*)v.data();
```

to

```
int* ptr = &(v.data()[0].p0);
```

Comment: Thanks @R Sahu. The wording "should be a sufficient guarantee" makes me think there is a non-zero risk that it will not. Sorry for being picky, but I really need this part to be robust, as it would be difficult to trace back and debug in production code.

Comment: @Samuel: Compilers can and do insert padding into structures. If you need the structure to be aligned to a specific size, you will need to explicitly tell the compiler to do that. Your choices are either language level or compiler directive level, and it how it is done differs across different compilers and between the host and CUDA GPU. You are going to need to choose a method and use it. You cannot assume it will just work, because it probably won't

Comment: @talonmies: Thanks ! This is now clear. So after searching a bit, a `#pragma pack (4)` just before the definition of the `struct` should do the job (where the number in the parenthesis, here 4, corresponds to the number of bytes per block for storing each field in the `struct`) ?

Comment: That is a Visual C++ only feature. As I commented above, https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/alignas is the C++11 way to do it.  The CUDA way is here https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#device-memory-accesses. I don't know whether nvcc honors alignas or not

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach, which would keep you from having to language-lawyer your way around formal and actual bugs, could be the following:

- Allocate the raw integers, e.g. using `std::make_unique<int[]>(2*dimension)`, or even with [`std::make_unique_for_overwrite`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58050872/1593077).
- Use an [`std::span<int>`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45723819/1593077) when you want to refer to the entire double-length of raw `int`'s.
- Only ever pass the span around to functions which need to use it (and not resize it).
- When you need a `struct S`, construct it on the spot from a pair of consecutive integers in the span. The construction will likely be optimized away by the compiler, i.e. if you have `foo(const S my_s)`, and you invoke `foo(S{my_ints[456], my_ints[457]})` - it's very possible that no actual construction will need to happen, and those `int`'s will just be placed in CPU registers to be used there.

---

(If you'd like to see how this would be done in code, ask in a comment.)